# Okio warning while implementing Proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard

Already implemented below given solution but none of them are working still facing below listed warning.

> Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

[image]

Comment: Have you read the basics of proguard? I suggest you read them first. Till then add minifyEnabled=false in build config

Comment: Yes I've read already but facing this problem even after using provided solution

Comment: minifyEnabled = false will solve your problem

Comment: and remove everything from proguard

Comment: but I want to use proguard and shrinkresources which will not work unitll I set minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines into your `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn java.nio.file.*
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
-dontwarn okio.**
```

**EDIT:** try to add this:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

into release buildType.

Comment: Show your `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 2):

Adding below lines to the proguard will ignore these warnings  [solution from here](https://github.com/square/okio/issues/60)

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
```

Comment: you can check the link of image I shared in which I've commented that solutions which are not working for me

Comment: add -dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement also